# Difficulties understanding, bipartite graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

I am looking back at some of my algorithms homework(exam soon haha), and I am having troubles understanding the solution to one of the questions.

**The Question**

[image]

**Tutor Solution**
[image]

I am having difficulties visualizing the solution, I understand that if you have an odd number of cycles than your graph cannot be bipartite. But as I stated, I don't understand the shortest path from s to u and v to s.

Comment: The definition of bipartite graph is wrong. If E subset AxB, then you can find the sets A and B by taking A to be the all the first components of the edges, and B all the second components. I guess it should say "E subset AxB union BxA"

Comment: I see you deleted your recent question on matrices. I was going to answer. If you still look for an answer let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The tutor's solution isn't as clear as it could be, since it talks about cycles, and the two paths don't necessarily form a cycle since they can share vertices. And the definition of bipartite graph is slightly wrong (or uses non-standard definitions of edges, cross-product etc. where the things aren't pairs but 2-element sets).

But instead of the definition as given, I'd just say that a graph is bipartite if the vertices can be coloured black or white, such that each edge goes between different-coloured vertices. (Equivalently you can simply say "the graph is 2-colourable").

From this definition, it follows that if there's an even length path between two vertices they must be the same colour, otherwise different colours. In the BFS on a bipartite graph, a vertex u is layer i has a path of length i from s to u, so all vertices in the same layer have the same colour. Thus there can be no edge between two vertices in the same layer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say G is bipartite. Then the vertex set can be divided into V1 and V2 s.t. every edge of G includes a vertex from each set. Then the vertices of every path in G alternate between V1 and V2, so the parity of the length of every path between every pair of vertices is the same. I.e., if G is bipartite and v,w are two vertices of G, then the length of every path connecting v & w is either even or odd.

If there is an edge (u,v) connecting two vertices in the same layer then this is violated. The BFS path to v and u have the same length, so same parity, since v & u are in the same layer. The edge between v & u gives us a path longer by 1, so of a different parity. Contradiction.